# Lie derivative of r-form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, lie-derivative

I actually try to read the Geometry, Topology and Physics by M.Nakahara and I'm stuck on the Lie derivative of a r-form and the demonstration of  $i_{[X,Y]}\omega = [L_X,i_Y]\omega $ . I found some proof of this relation like in this pdf [https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~lee/Xiaoman_Wu.pdf](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Elee/Xiaoman_Wu.pdf) . But this use a different definition of the Lie derivative than the Nakahara :

$L_X \omega =\frac{1}{r!} X^\nu\partial_\nu\omega_{\mu_1 \dots\mu_r}dx^{\mu_1}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{\mu_r} + \frac{1}{r!}\sum_{s=1}^r \partial_{\mu_s}X^\nu\omega_{\mu_1 \dots\nu\dots\mu_r}dx^{\mu_1}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{\mu_r}$

in Nakahara become :

$(L_X \omega)(X_1,\dots,X_r) = X[\omega(X_1,\dots,X_r)] -\sum_{i=1}^r \omega(X_1,\dots,[X,X_i],\dots,X_r) $

in the pdf.

I can't find how to connect this 2 definitions, thanks for help

Comment: Since the top expression is a differential form, try plugging in (vector field extensions of) vectors $X_1,\dots,X_r$ like in the bottom expression, and compare the two results. Note, since it is tensorial, you can just plug in a constant local extension, so that its derivatives are 0. Do you know how to write $Xf$ and $[X,Y]$ in coordinates?

Comment: Thank's for your response. I think I've some confusion about the action of a tensor on a form : if f it's a function, in coordinates $X[f] = X^\mu \partial_\mu f$, if f is a 1-form $X[f] = Xf = f[X] = <X,f>= X^\mu f_\mu$ but if f is a r-form I don't really know how to write into coordinates, for a 2-form $X[w_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu] = ?$. I think the commutator in coordiantes is $[X,Y] = (X^\mu \partial_\mu Y^\nu - Y^\mu \partial_\mu X^\nu)\partial_\nu $.

Comment: For functions, what you wrote is correct. For a 1-form $\omega$, I see what you are doing, using the natural pairing of $T^*M$ and $TM$ for $\omega(X) = \omega_\mu X^\mu$, but I wouldn't write this as $X(\omega)$ or $X\omega$. If I saw $Xf$ or $X$ applied to something like that without any further context, I would assume you are taking some kind of $X$ derivative (like a Lie derivative) whereas the natural pairing is an algebraic operation (no derivatives are taken). I don't see where you would have $X($2-form$)$ anywhere..?

Comment: Ok, it's just notation convention? Because for a function f I thought that in fact $L_X f = X[f]$ but for a r-form $L_X w = (X^\nu\partial_\nu w_\mu + \partial_\mu X^\nu w_\mu)dx^\mu$ which is different of $X[w]=<X,w>$ ? For the 2-form, that was just an example in order to understand the effect of a vector on a r-form but you're right I don't need this, I just have a confusion about the term $X[w(X_1,\dots,X_r)]$ but I finnaly understand that $w(X_1,\dots,X_r)$ is just a function !

Comment: yes $L_X\omega \neq \langle \omega, X\rangle$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've fund the solution :
$$\begin{align} (L_X w)(X_1\dots X_r)&=\frac{1}{r!}X^\nu \partial_\nu w_{\mu_1 \dots \mu_r}dx^{\mu_1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx^{\mu_r} (X_1 \dots X_r) + \frac{1}{r!}\sum_{s=1}^r \partial_{\mu_s} X^\nu w_{\mu_1\dots\nu\dots\mu_r}dx^{\mu_1}\wedge \dots\wedge dx^{\mu_s}\wedge\dots \wedge dx^{\mu_r} (X_1 \dots X_r)\\
&=\frac{1}{r!}X^\nu \partial_\nu w_{\mu_1 \dots \mu_r}\sum_{\sigma \in P} \text{sgn}(\sigma)X_{\sigma(1)}^{\mu_1} \dots X_{\sigma(r)}^{\mu_r} + \frac{1}{r!}\sum_{s=1}^r \partial_{\mu_s} X^\nu w_{\mu_1\dots\nu\dots\mu_r}\sum_{\sigma \in P} \text{sgn}(\sigma)X_{\sigma(1)}^{\mu_1} \dots X_{\sigma(s)}^{\mu_s} \dots X_{\sigma(r)}^{\mu_r}\\
&=\frac{1}{r!}X^\nu \partial_\nu \left[\sum_{\sigma \in P}w_{\mu_1 \dots \mu_r} \text{sgn}(\sigma)X_{\sigma(1)}^{\mu_1} \dots X_{\sigma(r)}^{\mu_r}\right] - \frac{1}{r!}X^\nu w_{\mu_1 \dots \mu_r} \partial_\nu \left[\sum_{\sigma \in P} \text{sgn}(\sigma)X_{\sigma(1)}^{\mu_1} \dots X_{\sigma(r)}^{\mu_r}\right]  + \frac{1}{r!}\sum_{s=1}^r \partial_{\mu_s} X^\nu w_{\mu_1\dots\nu\dots\mu_r}\sum_{\sigma \in P} \text{sgn}(\sigma)X_{\sigma(1)}^{\mu_1} \dots X_{\sigma(s)}^{\mu_s} \dots X_{\sigma(r)}^{\mu_r}\\
&=X\left[w(X_1,\dots, X_r)\right] - \frac{1}{r!}X^\nu w_{\mu_1 \dots\mu_s\dots \mu_r} \sum_{\sigma \in P} \text{sgn}(\sigma)\sum_{s=1}^r X_{\sigma(1)}^{\mu_1} \dots\partial_\nu X_{\sigma(s)}^{\mu_s}\dots X_{\sigma(r)}^{\mu_r} + \frac{1}{r!}\sum_{s=1}^r \partial_{\mu_s} X^\nu w_{\mu_1\dots\nu\dots\mu_r}\sum_{\sigma \in P} \text{sgn}(\sigma)X_{\sigma(1)}^{\mu_1} \dots X_{\sigma(s)}^{\mu_s} \dots X_{\sigma(r)}^{\mu_r}\\
&=X\left[w(X_1,\dots, X_r)\right] - \frac{1}{r!}X^\nu w_{\mu_1 \dots\mu\dots \mu_r} \sum_{\sigma \in P} \text{sgn}(\sigma)\sum_{s=1}^r X_{\sigma(1)}^{\mu_1} \dots\partial_\nu X_{\sigma(s)}^{\mu_s}\dots X_{\sigma(r)}^{\mu_r} + \frac{1}{r!}\sum_{s=1}^r \partial_{\nu} X^{\mu_s} w_{\mu_1\dots\mu_s\dots\mu_r}\sum_{\sigma \in P} \text{sgn}(\sigma)X_{\sigma(1)}^{\mu_1} \dots X_{\sigma(s)}^{\nu} \dots X_{\sigma(r)}^{\mu_r}\\
&= X\left[w(X_1,\dots, X_r)\right] - \frac{1}{r!} w_{\mu_1\dots\mu_s\dots\mu_r}\sum_{s=1}^r\sum_{\sigma \in P}\text{sgn}(\sigma)X_{\sigma(1)}^{\mu_1}\dots \left(X^\nu\partial_\nu X_{\sigma(s)}^{\mu_s}-X_{\sigma(s)}^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}X^{\mu_s}\right) \dots X_{\sigma(r)}^{\mu_r}\\
&= X\left[w(X_1\dots X_r)\right] - \sum_{s=1}^r w(X_1,\dots, [X,X_s], \dots,X_r)
\end{align}$$

I hope there aren't too many mistakes